# Migrating from XML + dataset to SQL + Entity Framework

Tags: sql, xml, entity-framework, xsd

Migrating XML + .xsd dataset version to SQL + Entity Framework.

I'm a novice to SQL databases now I have to.

Current scenario: my project has many XML files (40,000+) which can be loaded to one of `.xsd` dataset schema(~30). There are a lot of XML separation made to quickly choose one of the dataset and load data into it. Later the dataset is loaded into the UI but going on we expect maintainability and performance issues.

So now we want to migrate to SQL + Entity Framework.

How can I best utilize the existing code to migrate?

My main concern is how can I leverage existing code to create tables and load data to those created tables in SQL server.

How can existing XML files or dataset (`.xsd`) be used to develop tables and data in a SQL database?

Any other suggestions in order achieve my goal will help me a lot.

Comment: Start developing application and come back with specific question. The question(s) now is way too broad. For starters, you can learn a bit about SQL and inject all data into some DB - it's rather basic task, so people here would help you on that. Then, apply database first approach in EF (but I'd prefer Code-First with existing Database) and you'll have working database with application to manage it. Now copy all the code - you'll get lot of errors - tackling them one by one will let you replace all XML references to SQL.

Comment: **SQL** is **NOT** a database - it's a **query language** which is used by many database systems. You should really let us know what **actual RDBMS** you're planning on using, and add a corresponding tag to your question - is it `oracle`? `mysql`? `postgresql`? `sql-server`? Something else entirely??

Comment: @ Michał Turczyn
Thanks much for the suggestion, I agree I need to spend the time to understand SQL. 
My question was how to leverage the existing xmls and xsd's to create tables in SQL server and load data to those created tables from xml files. If the DB is created I understand applying database first EF will give classes to play with. 
My main concern is how can I leverage existing code to create tables and load data to those tables in sql server.